# Plotting the prime counting step function with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I’m trying to duplicate the step function that counts primes as shown [here](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/ss-b.htm).

I tried this code

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")

plt.autoscale(False)
plt.xlim(0, 31)
plt.ylim(0, 15)
y=0
for p in mylist:
    if sympy.isprime(p)==2:
        plt.plot(1,0)
    if sympy.isprime(p):
        x=p-1
        y=y+1
        #print(x,y)
        plt.plot(x,y, marker='.')
    else:
        x=p-1
        #print(x,y)
        plt.plot(x,y, marker='.')
        
plt.show()
```

[image]

But it fails at least in two respects:

(1) I could not make the non-primes start 1 unit above the primes. Mine move right.

(2) As in the referred plot, the x-axis should continue as 1,2,3,4,5… and each number plotted would be above the corresponding number. In my code the x-axis is not right.

Can you give me any hints about how to go about this? I just started to learn matplotlib.

I looked at the [step function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html)  but I don’t think it would work in this case. Thanks.

Edit:
I'm also trying to plot the reverse (the red line):
[image]

Comment: Side note: it's probably better (clearer) to collect relevant values in a list or array first, and then run one plotting call with those arrays. Also: read up on [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: You have `x=p-1`; perhaps that should be `x = p` or even `x = p + 1`. That would shift the plot to the right.

Comment: With point (2): do you mean you want every single integer number shown on the x-axis?

Comment: @9769953 Yes, as in here https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/ss-b.htm

Comment: @9769953 So, like collecting all integers in one array and primes in another array?

Comment: Something is unclear, do you want to count 1 as prime or not?

Comment: @mozway No, I don't want to include 1 as prime as in this plot here https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/ss-b.htm but I want to include it in the x-axis (exactly like in your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) the prime numbers (from a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)) before passing them to [`step`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html):

```
from sympy import isprime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 30

xs = list(range(N+1))
prime_xs = list(filter(isprime, xs))

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.step([0]+prime_xs, range(len(prime_xs)+1), where='post')
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Output:

[image: matplotlib python step plot prime numbers]

If you want all values, you could use a [`cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) (here with numpy)

```
from sympy import isprime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 30
xs = np.arange(N+1)
ys = np.cumsum(np.vectorize(isprime)(xs))

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.step(xs, ys, marker='o', where='post')
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Output:

[image: matplotlib numpy step plot prime numbers]

###### primes + non-primes

```
from sympy import isprime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 30
xs = np.arange(N+1)
primes = np.vectorize(isprime)(xs)
y1 = np.cumsum(primes)
y2 = np.cumsum(~primes)

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.step(xs, y1, marker='o', where='post', label='primes')
ax.step(xs, y2, marker='o', where='post', label='non primes')
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.legend()
```

[image: matplotlib numpy step plot prime numbers]

Comment: Looks great thanks! Can you also suggest the right strategy to keep both axes at the same scale without auto scaling? I had `plt.autoscale(False) plt.xlim(0, 31)
plt.ylim(0, 15)` but these don't seem right.

Comment: @zeynel see update. I changed a bit the logic to use the `where='post'` mode of `step`. I also provided a numpy approach to have all values.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll have to study the code to understand how this works. That was very helpful

Comment: This is fun. I was trying to do the reverse where non-primes move upwards and primes move horizontally. But I guess this cannot be done with `step()` I need to go back to drawing each line manually. I looked at the `stairs()` too but that only plots `y-axis`. Any suggestions, clues, how I can do this version? I added a sample plot to my question. I’m trying to plot the red line.

Comment: I haven't tested, but with the second approach you could soemthing like `primes = np.vectorize(isprime)(xs)) ; y1 = np.cumsum(primes) ; y2 = np.cumsum(~primes)`

Comment: Yes, that works (see update). Although it starts from 0 (unlike your drawing)

Comment: It took me a while to understand how this worked. Mostly all new to me but I think I understand it in general. But I still don’t understand the positioning of `xs` where you `vectorize(isprime)(xs)`. It must have something to do with the Bitwise negation operator `~` that you use defining `y2` because when I delete `(xs)` I get a `TypeError` on that line. What does `(xs)` do there? I’m puzzled how it is connected to `vectorize()` outside of the parenthesis of`vectorize()`.

And how does the the negation `y2 = np.cumsum(~primes)`
 remove the primes? Thanks again.

Comment: `vectorize(isprime)` just creates a new function that accepts an array as input, so you need to call it on `xs`. You can see it in two steps as `isprime_vectorized = vectorize(isprime) ; primes = isprime_vectorized(xs)`. This has nothing to do with the `~`. The `~` just swaps the `True`/`False` in the boolean array `primes`.